# Tensorflow: Weights of non-trainable model layers are updated

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, gpu

I have a trained model which is created using Keras. On this model I want to apply transfer learning by freezing all but the last convolutional layer. However, when I fit the model after freezing the layers I notice that some of the freezed layers have different weights. How can I avoid this?

I tried to freeze the entire model with `model.trainable = False` but this also didn't work out.

I am using python 3.5.0, tensorflow 1.0.1 and Keras 2.0.3

---

**Example script**

```
import os
import timeit
import datetime
import numpy as np
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Reshape, Permute
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import models
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

def conv_model(input_shape, data_shape, kern_size, filt_size, pad_size,\
                               maxpool_size, n_classes, compile_model=True):
    """
    Create a small conv neural network
    input_shape: input shape of the images
    data_shape: 1d shape of the data
    kern_size: Kernel size used in all convolutional2d layers
    filt_size: Filter size of the first and last convolutional2d layer
    pad_size: size of padding
    maxpool_size: Pool size of all maxpooling2d and upsampling2d layers
    n_classes: number of output classes
    compile_model: True if the model should be compiled

    output: Keras deep learning model
    """
    #keep track of compilation time
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    model = models.Sequential()
    # Add a noise layer to get a denoising autoencoder. This helps avoid overfitting
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(pad_size, pad_size), input_shape=input_shape))

    #Encoding layers
    model.add(Convolution2D(filt_size, kern_size, kern_size, border_mode='valid'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(maxpool_size, maxpool_size)))
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(maxpool_size, maxpool_size)))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(pad_size, pad_size)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(filt_size, kern_size, kern_size, border_mode='valid'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Convolution2D(n_classes, 1, 1, border_mode='valid'))
    model.add(Reshape((n_classes, data_shape), input_shape=(n_classes,)+input_shape[1:]))
    model.add(Permute((2, 1)))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    if compile_model:
        model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer='adam', metrics=["accuracy"])
    print('Model compiled in {0} seconds'.format(datetime.timedelta(seconds=round(\
          timeit.default_timer() - start_time))))
    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Create some random training data
    train_data = np.random.randint(0, 10, 3*512*512*20, dtype='uint8').reshape(-1, 3, 512, 512)
    train_labels = np.random.randint(0, 1, 7*512*512*20, dtype='uint8').reshape(-1, 512*512, 7)
    #Get dims of the data
    data_dims = train_data.shape[2:]
    data_shape = np.prod(data_dims)
    #Create initial model
    initial_model = conv_model((train_data.shape[1], train_data.shape[2], train_data.shape[3]),\
                               data_shape, 3, 4, 1, 2, train_labels.shape[-1])
    #Train initial model on first part of the training data
    initial_model.fit(train_data[0:10], train_labels[0:10], verbose=2)
    #Store initial weights
    initial_weights = initial_model.get_weights()

    #Create transfer learning model
    transf_model = conv_model((train_data.shape[1], train_data.shape[2], train_data.shape[3]),\
                              data_shape, 3, 4, 1, 2, train_labels.shape[-1], False)
    #Set transfer model weights
    transf_model.set_weights(initial_weights)
    #Set all layers trainable to False (except final conv layer)
    for layer in transf_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    transf_model.layers[9].trainable = True
    print(transf_model.layers[9])
    #Compile model
    transf_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4),\
                         metrics=["accuracy"])
    #Train model on second part of the data
    transf_model.fit(train_data[10:20], train_labels[10:20], verbose=2)
    #Store transfer model weights
    transf_weights = transf_model.get_weights()

    #Check where the weights have changed
    for i in range(len(initial_weights)):
        update_w = np.sum(initial_weights[i] != transf_weights[i])
        if update_w != 0:
            print(str(update_w)+' updated weights for layer '+str(transf_model.layers[i]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you compiled your model - you lost your previous weights, as they were resampled. You need to first transfer them, set weights to be not trainable and then compile it:

```
#Compile model
transf_model.set_weights(initial_weights)

#Set all layers trainable to False (except final conv layer)
for layer in transf_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

transf_model.layers[9].trainable = True

transf_model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4),\
                     metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Otherwise - weights would change as they are resampled.

**EDIT**:

The model should be compiled after changes - because during compilation `keras` is setting all trainable / not trainable weights in a list which is not further changed.

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction! But, still if you run my example with the order of these lines changed the weights of the model are updated. Weird thing is that if I do the same with a different model which only has Dense layers the layer freezing is working.

Comment: Also, in this example the model is compiled after setting the trainability of the layers: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_transfer_cnn.py

Comment: If I convert my script to the example above, the freezing seems to work. The question now is what makes the difference.

Comment: I found out why. During model compilation - a list of trainable weights is fixed - and during fitting, any changes made after compilation are not included.

Answer (score 1):

You should Upgrade Keras to [Keras v2.1.3](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.1.3)

This issue is just solved and this very last feature of freezing  BatchNormalization layers is now available in the recent release:

> trainable attribute in BatchNormalization now disables the updates of the batch statistics (i.e. if trainable == False the layer will now run 100% in inference mode).

**The Reason of error:**

In the previous versions, the variance and mean parameters of BatchNormalization layers couldn't set *untrainable* and it didn't work, although you sat `layer.trainable = False`.

Now, it works!